# Gravitational attraction and collision

Tags: java, processing, collision, gravity, energy

I made a simple program that simulates how a round object would behave with a roudn surface in an environment with gravity and collision.

My problem is related with the application of gravity: whenever an object get's very close to the attractor it starts reegaining height, what I think is causing the issue is that, let's say that the ball is touching the ground with very low speed, my program applies gravity and, sicne it will make contact, reverses the force and sends it into the air again.

I tried stopping the ball once it reached low enough speed, but the effect is overall unpleasing (it never is slow enough to make it seemless)

This is the code, what do you thin kis the mistake? As I listed only part of the code and it's pretty complciated I don't expect a specific response, but where do you think the issue could *generally* lie?
My guess is that I didn't respect the kinetic/potential energy relation, but I wouldn't know how to make it right either :/

```
    void update(ArrayList<Attracter>a) {
    pos.add(acceleration);
    println(acceleration.mag());
    for (Attracter ar : a)
      if (PVector.dist(pos, ar.pos)<ar.size/2+size/2) { 
        
        //send the compenetrated body back

        float difference=((ar.size/2+size/2)-PVector.dist(pos, ar.pos)+1);
        pos.sub(acceleration.copy().normalize().mult(difference));  
        
        //calculate the new acceleration
        PVector perpendicular= PVector.sub(pos,ar.pos).normalize(); //perpendicolare
        float angle=perpendicular.rotate(-PI/2).heading();//angolo dellatangente
        perpendicular.rotate(-angle); //normalizzo l'angolo
        acceleration.rotate(-angle); //normalizzo l'accellerazione
        
        PVector newAcceleration= PVector.fromAngle(perpendicular.heading()-acceleration.heading());
        acceleration=newAcceleration.setMag(acceleration.mag());
        acceleration.rotate(angle); //denormalizzo l'accellerazione
          
        //push the body forward
        pos.add(acceleration.copy().normalize().mult(difference));
        acceleration.mult(0.9); 
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you work with just positions and accelerations? Where are velocities? Accelerations should not directly influence the positions. Also, the speed of objects *should* increase when they get closer to an attractor, are you sure that what you observe is a wrong behavior?

Comment: I also don't know what the time per loop is. Velocity is acceleration * time, acceleration is force / mass, force is (G * mass1 * mass2) / distance^2 (G is the universal gravitational constant 6.673 x 10^-11 N m^2/kg^2). If you're recalculating position every second, you'd basically apply these assuming distance does not change for the second, and get a wrong, approximate answer. The shorter you make your time interval, the more accurate it will become.

Comment: @Alex short answer is because I don't know any better, could you link me to something that could explain that separation in more detail? Also I understand that the closer object are the strogner the force, however on Earth balls don't bounch indefinitely like this: https://streamable.com/llxnpy which is what I'm trying to mimic.

Comment: On Earth balls don't bounch infinitely because of dissipation of energy. There are different methods to deal with this, for example you can introduce an air resistance force which will be some function of the ball's speed. Also you can dissipate some energy on each collision of the ball with the Earth. That's what you probably tried to achieve with the last line `acceleration.mult(0.9);` but instead of acceleration you should operate with velocity, then this line will tell you that 10% of the balls speed goes away on each collision because of the dissipation of energy.

Comment: Actually, if the video is the result of your simulation, then maybe your calculations are almost correct, just the variable has a wrong name, it should be called 'velocity', not 'acceleration'. If this is the case, then you can try to introduce some air resistance which will be proportional to the ball's speed. Try this: as the first line of your `update` method put `acceleration.mult(Math.exp(-0.1*acceleration.mag()))`. You can try to play with the numerical value 0.1, increase or decrease it and see how it will influence your simulation.

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much for the input. I tried your method but it doesn't seem to get rid of the "error".
Printing the magnitude of the velocity vector I can see that, let's say I create a ball distant 0px for the attarctor with 0 velocity, that ball would get attracted at a certain speed, then reverse on contact therefore bouncing from gravity alone while in a still state.
As you can see in this video https://streamable.com/94ayp2 the ball gets close to 0 speed but then picks it up again. (stopping the ball when <1 in speed isn't smooth at all btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `+1` in the `difference calculation`, i.e. try to replace

```java
float difference=((ar.size/2+size/2)-PVector.dist(pos, ar.pos)+1);
```

with

```java
float difference=((ar.size/2+size/2)-PVector.dist(pos, ar.pos));
```